# GitHub API - How to add an admin collaborator?

Tags: github-api

I'm using the github api (v3) to create a repository in an organisation using my account. I am an admin of that organisation. I'm then using the collaborators endpoint to add a collaborator with admin permissions. I'm authenticating with an oauth token that has the 'repos' scope;

```
PUT /repos/:owner/:repo/collaborators/:username?permission=admin
```

Which returns a 204 leading me to believe the PUT has been successful. However, when I get the repository collaborators, or view the collaborators using the github UI the user that I have added has only write permission.

If I set the user to be admin via the UI and get the repository collaborators then the user has admin permission. If I do the PUT again, the user reverts back to having only write permissions.

Can anyone suggest what I may be doing wrong here or is this an issue with GitHub API?

Ta.

Comment: This does sound suspiciously like an API bug—it might be worth getting in contact with GitHub support, they are usually very responsive! As an alternative possibility, have you tried the Repository Invitations API preview (`Accept: application/vnd.github.swamp-thing-preview+json`)? It sends an invitation rather than adding the collaborator immediately, but it might provide another data point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer here was to include the permission level in the body, rather than as a query param.

Comment: to complete you i will add command that worked for me `curl -H "Authorization: token YOUR_TOKEN" "https://api.github.com/repos/YOUR_USER_NAME/YOUR_REPO/collaborators/COLLABORATOR_USER_NAME" -X PUT -d '{"permission":"admin"}'`

Answer (score 0):

Used this in python GH actions

```
import requests
                            
 # Create a dictionary to store the data for your new repository
                data = {
                "permission": "admin"
                }
                
                print(data)
                            
                # Send a PUT request to the API endpoint to add collaborator as admin
                response = requests.put(f"${{ env.api_base_url}}/repos/{user}/${{inputs.repo_name}}/collaborators/${{inputs.github_user_admin}}", json=data, headers={
                "Authorization": f"Bearer ${{ env.GH_TOKEN}}"
                })
                
                print(response.text)
                print(response.status_code)
                            
                # Check the status code of the response
                if response.status_code == 201:
                    print("Successfully added collaborator as admin")
                else:
                    print("Failed to add collaborator as admin")
```

Answer (score 0):

### Official doc

https://docs.github.com/en/rest/collaborators/collaborators?apiVersion=2022-11-28#add-a-repository-collaborator

### Api Full url

**For simple repositories:**

`https://api.github.com/repos/${yourUsername}/${repositoryName}/collaborators/${collaboratorUsername}`

**For organizations:**

`https://api.github.com/repos/${organizationName}/${repositoryName}/collaborators/${collaboratorUsername}`

### Get Token

Go to **Settings** ->  **Developer Settings**  ->  **Personal Access Token**  ->  **Tokens (classic)** .

Now, Generate a New Access token (classic) and add the minimum  privileges. In my case was enough:

[image]

### Nodejs snippet

```js
var yourUsername = "jrichardsz";
var repositoryName = "acme-api";
var collaboratorUsername = "jane_doe";

const headers = {
  'Authorization': 'token <her_the_token>'
}

var fullUrl = `https://api.github.com/repos/${yourUsername}/${repositoryName}/collaborators/${collaboratorUsername}`

var data = {permission:"push"}; // pull, triage, push, maintain, admin

var response = await axios.put(fullUrl, data, {headers: headers});
console.log(response.status)
```