# How to invite people to private GitHub repo through command line interface?

Tags: github

Usually one must click link "**Invite teams or people**" after accessing "https://github.com///settings/access" in a web browser.
But, I wish to do this through a **command line interface**, because I must invite
many persons. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5):

You could use the GitHub API in order to [add a collaborator](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/collaborators/#add-user-as-a-collaborator)

```
PUT /repos/:owner/:repo/collaborators/:username
```

See [for instance here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40672144/6309):

```
curl -H "Authorization: token YOUR_TOKEN" "https://api.github.com/repos/YOUR_USER_NAME/YOUR_REPO/collaborators/COLLABORATOR_USER_NAME" -X PUT -d '{"permission":"admin"}'
```

With permission level being one of:

> - **`pull`** - can pull, but not push to or administer this repository.

- **`push`** - can pull and push, but not administer this repository.
- **`admin`** - can pull, push and administer this repository.
- **`maintain`** - Recommended for project managers who need to manage the repository without access to sensitive or destructive actions.
- **`triage`** - Recommended for contributors who need to proactively manage issues and pull requests without write access.

(default is "push")

Update Sept. 2020, considering [GitHub CLI `gh` is now 1.0](https://github.blog/2020-09-17-github-cli-1-0-is-now-available/), it could be a good feature to add (a kind of `gh repo` `invite`)

In the meantime, you can use [`gh pi`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_api) to make a similar API call, automatically authenticated, with `-f` to add `POST` fields.

```
gh api repos/YOUR_USER_NAME/YOUR_REPO/collaborators/COLLABORATOR_USER_NAME" -f '{"permission":"admin"}'
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I could not come up with this option!

Comment: @user15181 I have added the GItHub CLI `gh api` alternative, since the old CLI `hub`  is now obsolete.

Comment: I am trying to do smth very similar but within an organization, I therefore adapted the endpoint but when I try to check if a user is listed as a collaborator with the command `gh api orgs/YOUR_ORG/repos/YOUR_USER_NAME/YOUR_REPO/collaborators/COLLABORATOR_USER_NAME`  it always return a 404, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @greghor Either the authentication [`gh auth login`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_login) did not work or you do not have access to the repository.

Comment: @VonC thanks for the reply. Using the gh CLI for features that are genuinely supported (ie: features that do not rely on the API) like `gh repo create MY_ORGS/MY_REPO -t MY_TEAMS` works perfectly fine. Can it nevertheless be a problem with `gh auth login` ?

Comment: @greghor In that case, no. I would invite you to post a separate question (with your OS, git and gh version) in order to have a closer look at the issue.

Comment: @VonC, done. See the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64371517/5872695)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the github cli or call the github api directly through curl. In this example I add a member to a company repo using the github cli:

`gh api "orgs/$target_repo/teams/$team/repos/$target_repo/$repo_new_name" -X PUT -f permission=admin`

Also see the docs: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/teams#add-or-update-team-repository-permissions

For your situation you can use this endpoint:

https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#add-a-repository-collaborator

Answer (score 0):

An alternative using [hub](https://hub.github.com/):

1- Check all users with permissions in your repo:

```
hub api --flat 'repos/YOUR_USER_OR_ORGANIZATION_NAME/YOUR_REPO/collaborators' | grep -E 'login|permissions'
```

2- Give permission to an user :

```
hub api 'repos/YOUR_USER_OR_ORGANIZATION_NAME/YOUR_REPO/collaborators/COLLABORATOR_USER_NAME' -H X:PUT -H d:'{"permission":"admin"}'
```