# Add users and teams to a repository through the GitHub API

Tags: api, github, github-api

I would like to add users or teams to GitHub repositories. I wasn’t able to find any possibility in the docs. Is there really no way to invite users even if the user is logged in through the oauth?

Comment: See here: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/collaborators#add-a-repository-collaborator

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to invite a user to a private github repo within an organisation using the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64371517/how-to-invite-a-user-to-a-private-github-repo-within-an-organisation-using-the-c)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75180445/bash-script-to-automate-to-adding-multiple-members-to-multiple-teams-using-githu/75220277#75220277